# Using clone() and html() to copy element does not retain old or new value

Tags: jquery, html, clone

I am using the following code to copy an element:

```
$($('<div></div>').html($('#elememt').clone())).html()
```

This works but does not keep the original elements value. I even tried it like this:

```
$($('<div></div>').html($('#elememt').clone().val('test'))).html()
```

with no luck.

Any idea on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: The snippets you posted have syntax errors.. there are too many `)`. A fiddle with more context would be helpful.

Comment: I missed part of my code when copying. Fixed.

Comment: $('<div></div>').html ? There a few things wrong with this. A selector cannot contain tags with < & >

Comment: @Krishna He's not selecting a div, he's [creating one](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2).

Answer (score 3):

You should use this

**$(selector).clone(true);**

This boolean value indicates whether event handlers should be copied along with the elements. The default value is to the false . So, when we were calling the .clone() method without passing any boolean value, it was just copying the elements but not the event handlers attached to it. But, when we pass the value true , it copies both the elements and any event handler attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

In your example there many error of syntax, too much `)`
to copy an element is sufficient to do this:

```
var new_element = $('#element').clone();
new_element.val('test');
```

and after append it where you want with new value:

```
$('#somediv').append(new_element);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('<div></div>')` creates a new jQuery-wrapped element in memory (this syntax can also be condensed to `$('<div/>')`), but you're not injecting it into the DOM anywhere.

You also don't explain what the intended outcome is of what you're trying to do, so it's hard to give you an accurate solution for your particular issue(s).

Nonetheless, check out a working example in the linked demo below.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HSGeG/)</kbd>